# What is the analog of jsp .tag-files in jsf or how to avoid coping and pasting jsf/facelets code?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, facelets

I think the title is clear enough so I only add an example of typical situation.

First block of code:

```
<div id="mailpanel">
    <h:panelGroup id="sendmailpane" styleClass="sendmailpane" layout="block"
                  rendered="#{userReports.reportRendered}">
        <o:inputTextarea promptText="#{msg['mail.listrules']}" promptTextStyle="color: #333"
               value="#{userReports.mailingList}" styleClass="maillist"/>
        <br/>
        <h:commandLink id="sendlink" value="#{msg['mail.sendLink']}"
                   action="#{userReports.sendMail}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</div>
```

Second (copied) block of code:

```
<div id="mailpanel">
    <h:panelGroup id="sendmailpane" styleClass="sendmailpane" layout="block"
                  rendered="#{projectReports.reportRendered}">
        <o:inputTextarea promptText="#{msg['mail.listrules']}" promptTextStyle="color: #333"
               value="#{projectReports.mailingList}" styleClass="maillist"/>
        <br/>
        <h:commandLink id="sendlink" value="#{msg['mail.sendLink']}"
                   action="#{projectReports.sendMail}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</div>
```

As you can see both blocks of code are almost similar but each of them uses different backing bean (but even beans have a superclass and all used in this example methods are actually methods of that superclass).

Comment: Why did you mention both JSP and Facelets in tags? In real you cannot use them both simultaneously. Or did you expect answers for both view technologies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ui:include src="commonFile.jsp">
    <ui:param name="reportsBean" value="#{projectReports}" />
</ui:include>
```

and in the `commonFile.jsp` you have:

```
<h:commandLink id="sendlink" value="#{msg['mail.sendLink']}"
               action="#{reportsBean.sendMail}" />
```

You cannot, alas, specify what params exactly are to be included. That's why I'm using the following practice: whenever you add a parameter, you put a comment ontop of the `commonFile.jsp` stating the name, the type and the required/optional. For example:

```
<!-- param: reportsBean, required -->
<!-- param: showLegend, optional, default: false, type: boolean -->
```

Comment: Is there any way to specify appliable params and their types in commonFile.xhtml?

Comment: no. I'm using comments ontop. see my updated answer for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

In JSP, you can use [custom tags](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html) for this. In Facelets, you can use [templating](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/giqxp.html) or the JSF 2.0 [composite components](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html) for this.

Comment: aren't composite components JSF 2.0? Not that the OP mentioned what version he is using.. :)

Comment: Composite components are great because you specify their optional and required attributes explicitly.